# How do I get size changes of Sketch symbol originals to reflect in artboard instances?

Tags: sketch-app

*I understand how to resize an instance of a symbol that's a layer on an artboard (and how to specify how that resizing should work on the "master" symbol). My question is not that, it's about resizing in the other direction.*

When editing a symbol in the Symbols area, if I resize it then the changed size isn't reflected on the artboards.

It appears that, basically, the layers are now considered to be resized versions of the original symbol (even though its size was never changed/overridden when originally inserted on the artboards).

Is there any way for me to get the layers to update on the various artboards after changing the original symbol size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to have them update automatically. There may be a plug in to do it though.

You can select all the symbols and right click -> set to original size. You can do it on the artboard or in the layers panel.

Comment: Ah, just being able to do so manually is good enough for now (I couldn't find that, even). A plugin search didn't reveal anything but it would certainly be a useful one in a complex project.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to do it manually. A quick way to find all of your symbol instances is via Arrange > Find Layer (Cmd + F) and typing in the symbol name. Highlight all of the instances, right-click, and choose Set to Original Size.